# Format Conditions based on value length

Tags: excel, vba

**How can I use VBA to Format a cell if it contains some value with a length greater than 1?**

(This rule should ofc apply to all cells in the range)

```
Set text_value = Range("$A:$A").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=--LEN($A1)>1")

   With text_value
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   End With
```

This is what I have tried, but does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Type to xlExpression, because you are using formula as a criteria and it will work.

```
Set text_value = Range("$A:$A").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=LEN($A1)>1")

   With text_value
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   End With
```